# Sending files from Vim with Mutt

Tags: vim, mutt

Suppose i'm in vim editing the file ~/hello.txt

I would like to send this files as an attachment with mutt from vim using some terminal command.

What does such a command look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command looks like this:

```
:!mutt -s "your subject" -a ~/hello.txt --  addressee@some.org < /dev/null
```

Since you're executing it within Vim and editing the attachment, you could also use this:

```
:!mutt -s "your subject" -a % -- addressee@some.org < /dev/null
```

You didn't say anything about a message body, so I just used an empty message body by redirecting stdin from /dev/null.

Answer (score 1):

How would you do it from your shell?

You can execute shell commands from Vim with:

```
:!command %
```

where `command` is the external command and `%` is the current file.